# Setting up SSL in domain mode mod_cluster JBOSS AS7

Tags: https, jboss

I am trying to setup SSL in Jboss domain mode cluster following instructions at **[domain mode cluster](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2147)**.

Now I need to run these cluster nodes in SSL. I have added following configuration in domain.xml that allows me to run each cluster in domain mode on SSL. If I have two nodes running with offset of 100 and 200 then I can access application separately at 8543 and 8643 on https as default port for jboss SSL is 8443.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http" scheme="http" redirect-port="443"/>
            <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="https" scheme="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
                <ssl name="ssl" password="mypassword" certificate-key-file="<path to truststore file>/jbossHttps.keystore" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="true"/>
            </connector>
```

There are few suggestions related to adding system properties and I have done that too.

```
<system-properties>
     <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="<path to truststore file>"/>
</system-properties>
```

Problem is I am looking to run my application over HTTPS using **mod_cluster** so as to access application as  `https://myapplication/`

What additional configuration changes I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Finally after hours of searching there is no single document/source of information available. Finally following detailed steps helped configure mod_cluster + ssl + jboss7.x

## Generate server certificate

Note: If you already have certificate created then this section can be ignored.

**Generate Private Key on the Server Running Apache + mod_ssl**
First, generate a private key on the Linux server that runs Apache webserver using openssl command as shown below.

```
[root@s4-app-dev jbossuser]# mkdir /etc/httpd/conf/certs
[root@s4-app-dev jbossuser]# openssl genrsa -des3 -out www.xyz.com.key 1024
```

**Generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)**
Using the key generate above, you should generate a certificate request file (csr) using openssl as shown below.

```
[root@s4-app-dev jbossuser]# openssl req -new -key www.xyz.com.key -out www.xyz.com.csr
```

**Generate a Self-Signed SSL Certificate**
For testing purpose, you can generate a self-signed SSL certificate that is valid for 1 year using openssl command as shown below.

```
[root@s4-app-dev jbossuser]# openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in www.xyz.com.csr -signkey www.xyz.com.key -out www.xyz.com.crt
```

## Apache SSL configuration

If you already have mod_cluster configured to listen to port 80 then remove that virtual host entry and make following configuration. Create ssl.conf as following.

```
[root@s4-app-dev jbossuser]# vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
This is the Apache server configuration file providing SSL support.
# It contains the configuration directives to instruct the server how to
# serve pages over an https connection. For detailing information about these
# directives see <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html>
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.
#

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

#
# When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the
# the HTTPS port in addition.
#
Listen 1.1.1.1:443

##
##  SSL Global Context
##
##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
##

#   Pass Phrase Dialog:
#   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
#   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is a internal
#   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

#   Inter-Process Session Cache:
#   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism
#   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

#   Semaphore:
#   Configure the path to the mutual exclusion semaphore the
#   SSL engine uses internally for inter-process synchronization.
SSLMutex default

#   Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG):
#   Configure one or more sources to seed the PRNG of the
#   SSL library. The seed data should be of good random quality.
#   WARNING! On some platforms /dev/random blocks if not enough entropy
#   is available. This means you then cannot use the /dev/random device
#   because it would lead to very long connection times (as long as
#   it requires to make more entropy available). But usually those
#   platforms additionally provide a /dev/urandom device which doesn't
#   block. So, if available, use this one instead. Read the mod_ssl User
#   Manual for more details.
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
#SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512

#
# Use "SSLCryptoDevice" to enable any supported hardware
# accelerators. Use "openssl engine -v" to list supported
# engine names.  NOTE: If you enable an accelerator and the
# server does not start, consult the error logs and ensure
# your accelerator is functioning properly.
#
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
#SSLCryptoDevice ubsec

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

# General setup for the virtual host, inherited from global configuration
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
#ServerName www.example.com:443

# Use separate log files for the SSL virtual host; note that LogLevel
# is not inherited from httpd.conf.
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

#   SSL Protocol support:
# List the enable protocol levels with which clients will be able to
# connect.  Disable SSLv2 access by default:
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

#   SSL Cipher Suite:
# List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
# See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

#   Server Certificate:
# Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
# the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
# pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  A new
# certificate can be generated using the genkey(1) command.
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/certs/www.xyz.com.crt

#   Server Private Key:
#   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
#   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
#   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
#   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/certs/www.xyz.com.key

#   Server Certificate Chain:
#   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
#   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
#   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
#   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
#   certificate for convinience.
#SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server-chain.crt

#   Certificate Authority (CA):
#   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
#   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
#   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

#   Client Authentication (Type):
#   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
#   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
#   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
#   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
#SSLVerifyClient require
#SSLVerifyDepth  10

#   Access Control:
#   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
#   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
#   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
#   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
#   for more details.
#<Location />
#SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
#            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
#            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
#           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
#</Location>

#   SSL Engine Options:
#   Set various options for the SSL engine.
#   o FakeBasicAuth:
#     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
#     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
#     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
#     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
#     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
#   o ExportCertData:
#     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
#     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
#     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
#     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
#     into CGI scripts.
#   o StdEnvVars:
#     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
#     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
#     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
#     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
#     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
#   o StrictRequire:
#     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
#     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
#     and no other module can change it.
#   o OptRenegotiate:
#     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
#     directives are used in per-directory context.
#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

#   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
#   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
#   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
#   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
#   approach you can use one of the following variables:
#   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
#     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
#     SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
#     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
#     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
#   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
#     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
#     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
#     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
#     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
#     works correctly.
#   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
#   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
#   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
#   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
#   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
#   "force-response-1.0" for this.
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
#   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
#   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>

LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so

NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443
MemManagerFile /var/cache/httpd

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
    <Location /mod_cluster_manager>
        SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Location>
    KeepAliveTimeout 60
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    ManagerBalancerName testcluster
    AdvertiseFrequency 5

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn

    SSLEngine on

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/certs/www.xyz.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/certs/www.xyz.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/certs/www.xyz.com.crt
    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
         AllowOverride None
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Once these changes have been made you should be able to reach to Apache over SSL [https://1.1.1.1/][1]

## Upgrade Jboss for mod_cluster and SSL

The Jboss 7.1.1.Final doesn’t work with mod_cluster and SSL configuration. It basically ignores the certificate configuration to SSL of mod_cluster. We need to upgrade to higher Jboss such as
Download higher source tag from Git https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/tree/7.1.3.Final 
If you already have Maven 3 installed

```
$ mvn install
```

If you don't have Maven 3

```
$ ./build.sh
```

## Creating self-signed certificates using KeyTool

Generating the key pair into a keystore (JKS), for RSA:

```
[root@s4-app-dev jbossuser]# keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore xyz_keystore.jks -alias xyz
```

Import server certificate into keystore

```
[root@s4-app-dev jbossuser]# keytool -import -alias xyz -file /etc/httpd/conf/certs/www.xyz.com.crt -storetype JKS -keystore /home/jboss-as-7.1.1.final/keystore/xyz_keystore.jks
```

To list keystore content

```
[root@s4-app-dev jbossuser]# keytool -list -keystore /home/jboss-as-7.1.1.final/keystore/xyz_keystore.jks
Jboss mod_cluster ssl configuration
```

In domain.xml add system properties for truststore and password.

```
<property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="<path to keystore>/keystore/xyz_keystore.jks"/>
<property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword" value="xyzmanish"/>
```

Modify mod_cluster subsystem to now listen to 444 and use keystore that we configured.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.1">
  <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp" proxy-list="1.1.1.1:443" advertise-security-key="xyzmanish">
   <dynamic-load-provider>
         <load-metric type="busyness"/>
   </dynamic-load-provider>
   <!-- SSL/TLS configuration for mod_cluster advertise-security-key -->
   <ssl password="xyzmanish" key-alias="xyz" ca-certificate-file="<path to key store>/keystore/xyz_keystore.jks"  certificate-key-file="<path to key store>/keystore/xyz_keystore.jks" cipher-suite="ALL" protocol="TLSv1"/>
  </mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>>
```

Once you make this changes restart the JBOSS server and try to access your application via Apache over SSL.